# Simple $scope test not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to do a simple $scope controller practice. The app should show the result expression if the text value is the correct one...

```
<scope-test>
    <h2>My Name?</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="text"/>
    <p>{{text}} {{result}}</p>
</scope-test>
```

And this is the app...

```
angular.module('angular-tests', [])
    .directive('scope-test', function(){
        return{
            restrict:'E',
            controller: function($scope){
                if ($scope.text === "alex") {
                $scope.result = "is correct!";
                } else {
                $scope.result = "is not correct!";
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Ng-model is the only thing working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each controller function called once per load (like a constructor). It means that you check your value only once at the start.

You need to create a function inside your controller, which will be ran by each change:

```
<scope-test>
    <h2>My Name?</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="changeHandler" />
    <p>{{text}} {{result}}</p>
</scope-test>

angular.module('angular-tests', [])
    .directive('scope-test', function(){
        return{
            restrict:'E',
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.changeHandler = function(){
                    if ($scope.text === "alex") {
                        $scope.result = "is correct!";
                    } else {
                        $scope.result = "is not correct!";
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution would be to include a watch in your directive.

**Angular Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
   .directive('scopeTest', function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.$watch('text', function() {
                  if ($scope.text === "alex") {
                     $scope.result = "is correct!";
                  } else {
                     $scope.result = "is not correct!";
                  }
            })
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<scope-test>
  <h2>My Name?</h2>
  <input type="text" ng-model="text"/>
  <p>{{text}} {{result}}</p>
</scope-test>
```

Hope it helps!

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/au2uL08u/

Answer (score 0):

Also note that your `directive` name needs to be camelCase. Then when you place your directive inside the template, you use hyphens for each word that begins with a capital.

```
<scope-test>
    <h2>My Name?</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="evaluateText()"/>
    <p>{{text}} {{result}}</p>
</scope-test>

angular.module('angular-tests', [])
  .directive('scopeTest', function(){
    return{
      restrict:'E',
      controller: function($scope){

        $scope.evaluateText = function () {
          if ($scope.text === "alex") {
            $scope.result = "is correct!";
          } else {
            $scope.result = "is not correct!";
          }
        };

        $scope.evaluateText();
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: ng-change needs to call evaluateText